# Start Androids WiFi-Manager by sending an intent?

Tags: android, wifi

I´m developing an application, where I´d like to have a button, which opens Androids built-in WiFi menu... (I don´t really want to implement scanning and connecting code by myself).

Is there any Intent I can send which opens this menu?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use [`ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK) action:

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to implement it yourself (so it looks like your app), the Android SDK offers the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)-class, which should do most of the work for you.

Comment: Oh, no, WifiManager is only small part of the story. You can check the implementation yourself: http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ohAXAHj6Njg/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiSettings.java&d=4. There are 13 classes, and they use hidden API. I would strongly recommend to avoid implementing custom WiFi settings screen, unless there are special scenarios that differentiate your application.

Comment: `WifiManager`s methods look pretty straight forward.

Comment: You probably didn't try to make UI that accepts all kinds of WiFi configurations. And this is only small piece of code compared to all different cases that should be handled there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the default Wifi settings dialog, you can use an intent with an [ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS) action

Comment: It looks like both `ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK` and `ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS` are handled identical. See  `AndroidManifest.xml` file for Settings.apk here: http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ohAXAHj6Njg/AndroidManifest.xml&d=0&l=103