# How can I establish wifi connection?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to write a application list AccessPoints and when you click one, a wifi connection dialog will open (like WiFi Manager or WiFinder) but I don't know how to Open the default connection dialog ?and how to receive the intent or event to call the connection dialog?

To be clear, I want to open a dialog like when you open Wi-Fi setting, click on one of configured wifi network list; and it open a dialog asking you connect or forget.

Comment: Please use proper spelling when asking questions. 'plz' and other 'text speak' abbreviations should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(enabled);
```

Comment: Hey , was it useful for you ?

Comment: thx for answer but I want to open a dialog like when you open Wi-Fi setting, click on one of configured wifi network list; and it open a dialog asking you connect or forget. Plz help

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6103159/931277).  The next post also mentions [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) which gives you finer control like a list of the configured networks.

Comment: thx for answer but I want to open a dialog like when you open Wi-Fi setting, click on one of configured wifi network list; and it open a dialog asking you connect or forget. Plz help

Comment: user1106392- did you find an answer to your problem? because I am also in need of the same problem.I have a list view with scanned result.But dont know how to connect to a selected item wifi name.Kindly help if you have the answer